# Etymology of 金槌

Tags: etymology

What's the etymology of hammer, 金槌? Jisho.org gives "mallet" for the 槌 kanji. Is the "金" kanji indicating "metal", or "golden", presumably as in colour? The English edition of Wiktionary [doesn't have etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E6%A7%8C), and the Japanese edition of Wiktionary doesn't have an entry at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

金槌 is `metal + mallet`, hence (metallic) hammer (typically used to drive metallic nails). This 金 means metal, not golden color nor money.

槌 and ハンマー (in Japanese) refer to mallets and hammers in general, including ones with metal, wooden, plastic and rubber heads. To refer to what is typically referred to as *hammer* in English, you usually have to say 金槌.

[image]

We have a word 木槌【きづち】 (wooden mallet), too, which is basically the same as 木製のハンマー.